# c++ cli timespan format is not working

Tags: c++, c++-cli, timespan

I'm trying to measure some code execution and I need to display in minutes:seconds.
Since I noticed the TimeSpan can format more easily, I tried to use:

```
TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan::FromTicks(complete-commence);
String elapsedTime = TimeSpan::Format("mm", ts.Minutes);
```

But is not working, despite the method exists in MSDN:

```
Error   1   error C3149: 'System::String' : cannot use this type here without a top-level '^'
Error   2   error C2039: 'Format' : is not a member of 'System::TimeSpan'
Error   3   error C3861: 'Format': identifier not found
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: String is a reference type, it is missing the ^ hat, TimeSpan doesn't have a Format() method.  Its ToString() method only works in .NET 4.0.  An obvious alternative is ts.Minutes.ToString().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax is wrong, it should be:

```
TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan::FromTicks(complete-commence);
String^ elapsedTime = ts->ToString("mm\\:ss"); // "mm\\:ss" is minutes:seconds
```

Note that this is loading the value from Ticks, not seconds or milliseconds.  If your input data is in milliseconds, for example, you'd use:

```
TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan::FromMilliseconds(complete-commence);
```

Comment: Indeed, thanks very much Hans and Reed. Thanks for the tip with mS!
rtb1->AppendText("COMPLETED ("+ String::Format("{0:mm\\:ss}", ts) + ")\n");